# Humble Bundle Closure Game: controls problem

Tags: games

When I start the Closure game the character keeps moving to the left as if I was pressing the left key on the keyboard. When I try to change the controls configurations the game closes.
Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the left key?  I sometimes experience this (not in this game) and pressing the same key usually corrects it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to press the left key but the problem persisted.

Comment: I have the same problem. Still no fix found

Comment: is there a log file? if so post it. another trick is to start the game via the terminal. If there is stderr, that should output to the terminal window,in which case you can see why your program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that some device (your keyboard for instance) is being detected as a joystick/gamepad, and this ruins the input. If you don't actually have/use any gamepads/joysticks, try removing the joystick support module:

```
sudo rmmod joydev
```

I had this problem myself, and found this quick fix here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996702. I'm actually using this Microsoft Wired 600 keyboard mentioned in the forum, so it would be interesting to know if you're using the same keyboard.